# google app engine java basic authentication

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I have started to write a webApp in Eclipse where ECMAScript6 on the client (testing mostly on chrome on Win7) communicates with the server side written in Java7 on Jetty+GAEplugin via xmlHttpRequest (1 get request, user edits data, 1 post requests ). if it gets more I will move to webSockets).

The client code does not know anything about logins and provides neither user name nor password because as I understand, the browser and the user handle that. On the server side I response with 401 if basic authentication is missing.

But when testing, the browser does not ask the user for any password and does not send a second request (FF the same effect). No errors. Chrome development console claims that my
response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate","Basic realm=\"bus driver\"");
did not reach it.

A subset of my targeted user baser does not have a google account nor FB nor twitter. So OpenId nor OAuth are of no use for that subset. OAuth doc says: " The user signs in using her Google account, .." . Any way I try to search, directs me to ways to store user data, but I have problems with the communication between browser and servlet.

I have read that I should edit web.xml, but I cannot see how to plug my home-built authentication into that. Web.xml would be okay for me because there will be about 3 pages sharing the same   (*3roles=9pages).

My software should be up to date. Oracle claims that I should stop using Java 7, but I cannot get local GAE to run on Java 8 ...

Just testing on FF and looking for stupid errors I may have made last night. FF claims: InvalidStateError: An aatempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.  Hmm seems that there is at least something wrong with my XMLhttpRequest (it worked in chrome at least without authentication). I could test GET with authentication but without ECMAscript... Still my main question remains, where is the example with old school authentication on the new kid, the cloud?

Logcat is empty. I have seen the logs getting filled in TomCat or for Android. I may have to dig into this.

Comment: Hi Arne, I believe you're messing some concepts. On the one hand, your client code must be authorized to interact with the Google Cloud remote services. That depends on your credentials. On the other hand, you should enable a user authentication handler for your users based on user/password or whatever you want. Thus, you'll get two smaller problems to solve and ask about.

Comment: Some update: I tried to use code for form based authentication for my basic authentication client page. And basic authentication  is bad, because there is no Unicode support, ugly base64 commands come into my code, and I have read that one cannot inform the user that the server got  userName and passWord they just entered in their whole glory, but unfortunately the user entered wrong. Instead the message looks like a network hick-up. I do not know what a Google Cloud remote service is. As far as I understand everybody can call my webpage, if they know the password, they can enter data and my q

Comment: Hi Arne, I'm afraid I didn't understand what you wrote. If you still need help, could you please elaborate more?